# Can a capacitor be used for biasing?

Tags: capacitor, bias

I have a load switch IC [SiP32431DN](https://www.vishay.com/docs/66597/sip32431.pdf) which internally has a comparator at its input stage (connected to its on/off pin). If I connected a, let's say, 100nF capacitor to this on/off pin, would that be enough to keep the load switch off, even if the pin is left floating (assuming that I discharged the capacitor before going into floating mode)?

The voltage at which the load switch turns on is around 0.6V.

Comment: What load switch IC? Link to datasheet or at least part number please.

Comment: why do you plan to connect a capacitor, instead of a high-ohmic resistor to ground?

Comment: https://www.vishay.com/docs/66597/sip32431.pdf

Comment: The reason for not using a resistor (even in the MOhm region) is ultra-low power.

Comment: but you're not achieving that any more with a capacitor, which would be a very low-impedance sink for switching load.

Comment: The load is switching very infrequently (between once a minute and once an hour). So the additional capacitor would not consume much energy.

Comment: This pin should be driven by a static, bipolar CMOS pin. Then the voltage is perfectly well defined, and no additional impedance of any sort is needed.

Comment: Yeah, I can't imagine the off-state leakage current through the pin to be even *remotely* relevant; the 5.5V input leakage is 0.04 nA, at 3.3 V it's 0.01 nA, and not specified at all for an input of 0V; we can quite safely assume it's orders of magnitude below the off-state input current.

Comment: @trevor what I meant is that while the DC current coming out of that pin is probably totally negligible at low pin voltages, adding a capacitor to that input suddenly introduces a good path for parasitic AC current to go to ground, which is just as likely to do much more harm to your average power consumption.

Comment: @trevor but maybe I'm getting ahead of myself: I assume you wouldn't have asked this question if you didn't measure a significant current coming out of that pin in off-mode?

Comment: @TimWilliams it's driven by an STM32 MCU, which, while in some deepsleep mode, will set the pin to high impedance. If you have a link to a BiCMOS chip that acts like a buffer, I can have a look at it.

Comment: Then don't use that MCU, or that sleep mode.  Alternately, accept that some current is drawn during transitions, e.g. using a buffer gate with a large feedback resistor from OUT to IN.

Comment: @MarcusMüller no, I didn't measure currents on that pin. The reason why I asked is: The pin is high impedance on both sides at certain times (both the end going to the load switch and the end being controlled by me). I thought that the only thing that might drive the voltage of this pin high, would be some EMI. And that adding a capacitor would short-circuit this EMI. I haven't tried it out yet whether the load switch will go on at times, when it actually shoud not. Because that would be what I don't want: an "automagically" turned on switch while it should stay off.

Comment: so, add a resistor to ground, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

> would that be enough to keep the load switch off, even if the pin is left floating (assuming that I discharged the capacitor before going into floating mode)?

Probably not. This cannot be answered without reading the datasheet, and even then, it's likely to not be specified. (Combining a capacitor's floating end with a floating input just screams "undefined behaviour", and it's not sensible to assume that it's something any designer or verification engineer had in mind you'd want to do.)

I don't see any case where you would want to connect a capacitor to a floating input (which probably goes into a FET gate); you're just asking for unexpected dynamic behaviour, and if it's not *really* floating but sources a tiny current, over time your capacitor will charge.

So, bad idea, honestly. Do what this pin is designed for: connect it to the wanted potential (ground or VCC) with a high-value resistor.